# Calling a code activity compiled as x86 from a work flow in TFS build 2010

Tags: workflow-foundation, tfsbuild

**Background**

We have a need, or at least a desire, to call a 3rd party DLL that will only load/run when called from a .Net assembly compiled as x86. For compatibility we normally compile our .Net programs as x86 anyway so this hasn't been a problem in the past. I'm looking into getting a x64 version, but it doesn't look promising.

**The Real Problem**

When I compile our Code Activity as x86 instead of "Any CPU" the build agent throws an error stating that it cannot find our code activity.

**Questions**

- Is there something special I need to
  do in the work flow to tell it the code activity's
  assembly is x86?
- Can I force a code activity to run as
  x86 even if it's compiled Any CPU?
- Is there a way to force the whole
  work flow to run as x86?

Answer (score 0):

The TFS Build 2010 is 64 bits which probably causes the problem.

But why do you want to compile your code activity that is consumed by team build as an x86 assembly? Does that code activity using the 3rd party dll?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem that one code activity in our workflow did some assembly loading and reflection for documentation purposes (meanwhile in TFS 2012 :)).

We have created a small solution for a command line exe linking to all needed code activity cs files. In the exe we call the activity with something like:

```
        CreateSpecs createSpecsAction = new CreateSpecs();
        var Arguments = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                {"BinariesDirectory",BinariesDirectory},
                {"FileMask",FileMask},
                {"ExcludeFiles",ExcludeFiles},
                {"ResultFilePath",ResultFilePath}
            };

        var output = WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(createSpecsAction, Arguments);
```

In our workflow template we call the exe when we build x86 and do a normal call to the activity otherwise. For debuging the activity we switch to AnyCPU.